# Windows 10 Lumia 640 - hotspotting desktop - no internet access?

Tags: windows-10-mobile

I'm trying to download some updates and my broadband at home is pretty slow right now. I have 10 gig on my network right now so I decided to hotspot my phone and get my desktop connected to it so I can download over 3G. However, upon connecting my desktop to the hotspot on my phone, my desktop keeps telling me that it's unable to connect to the internet, although it is connecting to my phone.

Attached you'll find a small picture of what I mean, any help right now would be massively appreciated.

[image]